# Stride on image using Opencv C++

Tags: image, visual-c++, opencv, stride

I am on windows and use opencv 2.4.2 on C++.
I read an image with `imread` and put it in a Mat object. 
After that, i get a pointer on the raw data using the function `ptr` of the Mat class.
I would like to know how works `imread` when the image contains stride. Is there stride in the data of the Mat or only data of pixels ?

Additional information: I need the raw data because I am using a code written with array and I don't want to change it for the Mat class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stride is that each new row of pixels in the cv::Mat doesn't start after the end of the last row.
This is because the memory is faster if it starts on a multiple of 4bytes - so it only matters if the number of bytes in a row (number of pixels * number of colours) isn't a multiple of 4.

You can check .isContinuous() will return true if there is no stride

The safest way of accessing an image is to loop over all the rows and use .ptr(row) to get a pointer to the start of the row, then do any processing on that row.

If you need to mix opencv with other libs you can create a cv::mat that will use your own memory for the data and you can tell opencv that there is no stride on this

For lots of details see https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Comment: Would be worth noting that OpenCV does not add padding by default to images. The only two ways to have strides different than channels*width are to manually import an image with such padding (from a codec, or whatever) or to create a subimage: `cv::Mat roi(bigImage(Rect(5,5,100,100)));` I have never seen see any padding coming from imread or VideoCapture.

Comment: @vasile Sorry, I am a bit confused about what Martin said and what vasile said. If I read with imread an image containing stride, my cv::Mat will not be continuous right ? Therefore, it kept the stride.

Comment: I think `imread` will never create matrices with stride. But there are other situations when you may have strides, so it's better to keep your code as Martin recommended. imread decodes images from various formats, and the decision to pad it for aligning is up to `imread`. And to the best of my knowledge, it does not pad images

Comment: @vasile Ok, I understand. In my case,  I have to deal with any kind of image so sometimes images can have stride. I will try as Martin said to be sure to access images correctly.

Comment: IIRC imread doesn't repack images form an external lib. But those images may not be contiguous if the external lib chooses to do it that way. I'm pretty sure that cv::Mat images created locally will have a stride - check the source! Like RGB/BGR and endianess of 16bit pixels, it's one of those things you have to know about in image processing - because it will catch you!

Comment: @MartinBeckett ok, I see that I can check the stride with the function isContinuous. But how can I check the matrix to know if the image is BGR or RGB ? I didn't see any function in the documentation.

Comment: @Seltymar - openCV internally use BGR (for 8UC3 images) any file load will convert to this order

Comment: I think the following is imprecise: `You can check .isContinuous() will return true if there is no stride`. In fact, if `isContinuous()` returns `true` it means that `stride == cols`, so the "stride" becomes the same of the image width. What is zero in that case is, maybe, the padding.