# How to copy cv::Mat & Img to unsigned char* img?opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

How to copy "Mat& imgSrc"  to "unsigned char* imgSrc"?

```
void BGR2NV21( unsigned char* bgrData, int w, int h, unsigned char* nv21Data)
{.............}

int enhanceRGB( cv::Mat& fieldFaceImgSrc, int iWidth,int iHeight, cv::Mat& faceImgDst)
{
    cv::imwrite("enhanceInput.jpg", fieldFaceImgSrc); //it's ok

    cv::Mat faceBackupData;
    faceBackupData = fieldFaceImgSrc.clone();       //it's ok
    cv::imwrite("enhanceput.jpg", faceBackupData);  //it's ok

    unsigned char*pcfieldFaceDataNV21 = (unsigned char*)faceBackupData .data;

    BGR2NV21(pcfieldFaceDataNV21,                   //it's bad,pcfieldFaceDataNV21  is bad data;
             iWidth, iHeight, pcfieldFaceDataNV21);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you know it's bad data on that line?  How do you know it's good before?

Comment: Opencv pads rows to 32bit boundaries, If you image lines are multiples of 4bytes you will get tearing just copying the data

Comment: `uchar *  ptr (int i0=0)`  Returns a pointer to the specified matrix row.

Comment: In fact,the variable of pcfieldFaceDataNV21  no data.. and can't transmit  to the function of BGR2NV21( unsigned char* bgrData, int w, int h, unsigned char* nv21Data)..

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error message or is the image just "wrong"?

Two obvious things to check, have you passed image width and height the right way around? It's a constant source of pain in image between camera APIs (x,y)  and image processing matrix APIs (row,col)

And opencv pads rows of an image to 32bit (4byte boundaries) see [Stride on image using Opencv C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572156/stride-on-image-using-opencv-c)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason why it may failed is about the management of the channels.
OpenCV's `Mat` object store the data continuously if they are not a submatrix.
This storage follow the raw line ordering that mean:

The matrix :
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|
|7 8 9|

will be stored a a linear pointer in that order : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

That is also true for the channels i.e. let supose two pixel with the value [255,64,128] and [64,12,34] corresponding the the coordinate row = 0, col =0 and row =0 col = 1 they will stored in memory continuously (the six first values of the `data` will be 255,64,128,64,12,34)

Now the easiest way to copy the `data` pointer of `Mat` object to another data pointer can:

`std::memcpy(dst,src,rows*cols*elemsize);` or if you pass the `Mat` object:

```
if(obj.isContiguous())
  std::memcpy(dst,src.ptr(),src.rows*src.step); // if you data are of type unsigned char src.step == src.cols otherwise src.step = src.cols*src.elemSize()
else
   for(int r=0;r<src.rows;r++,dst+=src.step)
      std::memcpy(dst,src.ptr(r),src.step);
```

Comment: cv::imwrite("enhanceInput.jpg", fieldFaceImgSrc); //it's ok
 cv::Mat faceBackupData;
 faceBackupData = fieldFaceImgSrc.clone();
 cv::imwrite("enhanceput.jpg", faceBackupData);   //it's ok

 unsigned char *testdata = (unsigned char*)malloc(iWidth * iHeight * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
 memcpy(testdata, faceBackupData.ptr(), iWidth * iHeight * 3);

 cv::Mat FaceData(iHeight , iWidth, CV_8UC3, testdata);
 cv::imwrite("testput.jpg", FaceData);           //it's bad

Comment: why do you use imwrite ? (cv::imwrite("testput.jpg", FaceData); //it's bad)

Answer (score 0):

so sorry,it always some questions,code is :

```
int enhanceRGB( cv::Mat fieldFaceImgSrc, int iWidth,int iHeight, cv::Mat& faceImgDst)
{
cv::imwrite("enhanceInput.jpg", fieldFaceImgSrc); //it's ok
    cv::Mat faceBackupData;
    faceBackupData = fieldFaceImgSrc.clone();
    cv::imwrite("enhanceput.jpg", faceBackupData);   //it's ok

    unsigned char *testdata = (unsigned char*)malloc(iWidth * iHeight * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(testdata, faceBackupData.ptr(), iWidth * iHeight * 3);
    cv::Mat FaceData(iHeight , iWidth, CV_8UC3, testdata);
    cv::imwrite("testput.jpg", FaceData);           //it's bad
}
```

Comment: Edit your original post.

Comment: Why not doing simply : fieldFaceImgSrc.copyTo(FaceData); ?